# Implementing checksums in Java migrations

Tags: flyway

My Java migrations currently do not implement the MigrationChecksumProvider interface.  I am wondering if they should.

I do not understand what role checksums play in Flyway.  Would someone explain this to me, please?  Moreover, if I implement MigrationChecksumProvider, how should a checksum be computed for a given migration?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checksum are used for (accidental) change detection of migrations, which would invalidate the guarantee that the schema can be recreated exactly.

For Java migrations, the sky is the limit as to what you can do. It is therefore your call as to how you want to implement checksums to detect changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think most of the time you want to calculate the checksum based upon the content of the class file in question.  We are doing that like this....

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.zip.CRC32;

import org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.jdbc.JdbcMigration;
import org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.FileCopyUtils;
import org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.Log;
import org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.LogFactory;

/**
 * Utility class for checksum calculations.
 * 
 */
public final class Checksums {

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(Checksums.class);

    private Checksums() {
        super(); // singleton
    }

    /**
     * Calculates a checksum based on the given JdbcMigration. It builds the checksum from the byte content of the given
     * migration class file using the same {@link CRC32} method as used by
     * {@link org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationResolver}
     * 
     * @param migration
     * @return the checksum
     */
    public static final Integer checksum(JdbcMigration migration) {
        Integer checksum = null;

        Class<?> migrationClass = migration.getClass();
        String migrationClassFilePath = migrationClass.getName().replace(".", System.getProperty("file.separator")) + ".class";
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        try {
            inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(migrationClassFilePath);
            byte[] classContent = FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(inputStream);
            final CRC32 crc32 = new CRC32();
            crc32.update(classContent);
            checksum = (int) crc32.getValue();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            LOG.error("Problem calculating checksum for class " + migrationClass.getName(), ioe);
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    LOG.error("Problem closing input stream to " + migrationClassFilePath, ioe);
                }
            }
        }
        return checksum;
    }    
}
```

Then you can create a base class that looks something like

```
public abstract class JdbcMigrationWithChecksum implements JdbcMigration, MigrationChecksumProvider {

    @Override
    public Integer getChecksum() {
        return Checksums.checksum(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this really dangerous? If you change your java version for example, the checksum of your class will change right?

Comment: @michael_bitard
Worse than that, checksum will very likely not work across different platforms (windows/linux etc.) and is not even guaranteed to be the same on the same machine - see http://stackoverflow.com/q/41970013/924597

Comment: Thanks @Shorn, that's why I ended up writing this plugin: https://github.com/agileek/java-checksum-flyway-maven-plugin it computes the checksum of the .java file, and I generate an enum which contains all the Checksums associated to the .java files

Comment: @michael_bitard that looks interesting however the Checksum it calculates is a long and getChecksum() expects an Integer... Am I missing something?

Comment: You are right, I'm using standard crc32 checksum which computes a long and flyway expects an int. Feel free te raise an issue, on even a pull request.