# How to use javac to create binary identical class files across different platforms?

Tags: java, java-8, aws-lambda

I write my AWS Lambda functions in Java.
The tool I use to upload my lambdas ([Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lambda_function.html#source_code_hash)) wants to use the SHA-256 hash of my jar file to track if a new version of a lambda needs to by uploaded.

The problem is, different JDKs on different OS platforms (Windows and Linux) create slightly different bytecode (even when using the same "update" version of the JDK).  This means, if I upload a lambda on Windows, then re-run the process on Linux - it will detect a different hash code for the jar and re-upload the lambda jar unnecessarily.

**The question**:
How do I force javac to create identical bytecode on different OS platforms?

Comment: Slightly different how?

Comment: ^This. Can you provide two example .class files?

Comment: Slightly different in the binary content emitted. When I diffed them in winmerge a few of the non-text bytes were different. I will try and post a screenshot.

Comment: No kidding. 'Slightly different in the binary content emitted' **HOW?** Is there some difference between 'different bytecode' and 'different in the binary content emitted' that you're keeping from us? Or are you just pointlessly repeating yourself? And don't post screenshots here. Do some work: analyze the difference and describe it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t enforce that. There are several unspecified details about the generated class files, like how the byte code of certain source code expressions has to look exactly or the order of members or attributes.

Since there is no requirement to produce exactly the same file in each run, the compiler implementation does not even try. It’s fair to assume that when you execute the same software with exactly the same input (not only the same source code, but also the same options), it will produce the same output, but that does not only require the same compiler version, but also the same JRE.

Unfortunately, there *might* be different behavior even with the same implementation and input. E.g., there were attempts to randomize the hashing of `java.util.HashMap` in some Java 7 implementations and it wouldn’t be surprising if `javac` stores certain artifacts in a `HashMap`. This does not apply to Java 8, but might apply to the immutable maps to be introduced in Java 9. Whether the compiler will use that feature is not predictable.

So if you found a particular jdk version that reproducibly generates exactly the same byte code, you might be fine with it now, but have to be aware that the next version might not have that property.

It has not been addressed so far that even having the same bytecode does not guaranty to have the same `jar` file, as the order of the files within the jar files is unspecified. It might depend on the system specific file iteration order. Further, since jar files are zip files which store timestamps, newly compiled class file do definitely yield a different file, unless you are taking additional measures, e.g. enforce a particular timestamp for all entries.

Answer (score 2):

For any body that stumbles across this question:

- the first thing to look at is to check the vendor of the JDK on each platform

Turns out I had the same version/update level, but was actually using different JDKs (duh).

I was using Oracle JDK on Windows and OpenJDK on Linux.  Once I changed these to Azul Zulu JDK (u112) on both Windows and Linux - it appears that exactly the same bytecode is being generated, at least for the limited amount of Java code I've written so far (though as per Holger's answer, it's apparently not to be relied upon).

Answer (score 0):

In the build process of Eclipse, the following is routinely checked for sanity: do any compiled class files from projects that have no changes in git since the last baseline, have any binary difference vs. the jar file from that baseline. Experience tells that indeed differences only occur when relevant changes have been made in the compiler.

This is not a guarantee, but empirical evidence that *normally* the same compiler version will produce the same bytes when compiling the same sources.

In this case the compiler is ecj.

See a [recent example logfile](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/I20170127-2200/buildlogs/comparatorlogs/buildtimeComparatorUnanticipated.log.txt) from the comparator (will be removed soon), that did signal unexpected class file changes, which were then traced back to a specific compiler change. The corresponding [logs of a release](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.6.2-201611241400/buildlogs/comparatorlogs/buildtimeComparatorUnanticipated.log.txt) are expected to be empty.